# How to extract specific values in a column in python /kaggle dataset

Tags: python, regex, pandas, kaggle

Im trying to extract the following fields from the "jobpost" column:

```
  1.Job Title
  2. Position Duration
  3. Job Responsibilities
  4. Required Qualifications
```

in the https://www.kaggle.com/madhab/jobposts/data. Ive tried slicing and regex but im still not able to get the values i wanted.

Ive tried to extract from one of the column in jobpost and use regex but still couldnt get the result

```
 gh = df2[2] 
 pattern = re.compile(r'JOB TITLE:.*\S|POSITION DURATION: .*\S|POSITION LOCATION: .*\S|JOB DESCRIPTION: .*\S |JOB RESPONSIBILITIES: .*\S|REQUIRED QUALIFICATIONS: .*\S|REMUNERATION: .*\S')
```

The output is

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(43, 74), match='JOB TITLE:  Country Coordinator'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(76, 122), match='POSITION DURATION:   Renewable annual contract'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(124, 159), match='POSITION LOCATION: Yerevan, Armenia'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(161, 219), match='JOB DESCRIPTION:   Public outreach and strengthen>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1141, 1192), match='REMUNERATION:  Salary commensurate with experienc>
```

As you can see i could not extract "JOB RESPONSIBILITIES:" and "REQUIRED QUALIFICATIONS:" values. I even tried to do this but getting no result

```
  aa= "JOB RESPONSIBILITIES:  \r\n- Working with the Country Director to provide environmental information\r\nto the general public via regular electronic communications and serving\r\nas the primary local contact to Armenian NGOs and businesses and the\r\nArmenian offices of international organizations and agencies;\r\n- Helping to organize and prepare CENN seminars/ workshops;\r\n- Participating in defining the strategy and policy of CENN in Armenia,\r\nthe Caucasus region and abroad.\r\nREQUIRED QUALIFICATIONS:  \r\n- Degree in environmentally related field, or 5 years relevant\r\nexperience;\r\n- Oral and written fluency in Armenian, Russian and English;\r\n- Knowledge/ experience of working with environmental issues specific to\r\nArmenia is a plus."

pattern= re.compile(r"(?s)JOB RESPONSIBILITIES: .*")
print(pattern.match(gh).group())
```

output:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

So how do i solve this problem what is the method should i use in order to get the Values i want? im still newbie. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the text of the `jobpost` column is structured consistently (I've only looked at the online preview of the data) you can to use the subsequent stop word as anchor, e.g. all text from one stop word till you reach the next one:

```
(?s)JOB TITLE:.*(?=POSITION LOCATION)
```

If the stop words are in variable order, you can use a negative assert with alternations, e.g.

```
(?s)JOB TITLE:((?!POSITION LOCATION|JOB RESPONSIBILITIES|REQUIRED QUALIFICATIONS).)*
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xZ7m82/1)

Comment: i did this--> (pattern = re.compile(r"(?s)JOB TITLE:((?!POSITION LOCATION|JOB RESPONSIBILITIES|REQUIRED QUALIFICATIONS).)*")  but it wont still give the full values. Im confused actually sorry

Comment: @nabskim Maybe you need to show more of your code. And can you set up a regex101 demo that shows the problem, please?

Comment: @nabskim Just to be clear, the suggested patterns only give you one block of information. To obtain an all the texts you need to create several of these patterns and adjust them accordingly, e.g. from one stopword to the next, and from that one the next, etc.